# How can I dry helper methods declarations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a lot of helpers defined which all basically do the same.

```
def subtitle(page_subtitle)
  content_for(:subtitle) { page_subtitle }
end

def header(page_header)
  content_for(:header) { page_header }
end

def auto_header(page_auto_header)
  content_for(:auto_header) { page_auto_header }
end

def header_image(page_header_image)
  content_for(:header_image) { page_header_image }
end

def bodyclass(page_bodyclass)
  content_for(:bodyclass) { page_bodyclass }
end
```

And there are many more...

My question is how can I DRY this code?

I tried something this but I didn't work

```
content_for_helpers = ["title","subtitle","logocolor"]
content_for_helpers.each do |helper|
  def helper(helper)
    content_for(helper.parameterize.underscore.to_sym) { helper }
  end
end
```

Comment: This looks like code smell to me. What does your view look like? I'll bet there's a better way to do it.

Comment: I'm sure also. Would you show me a better way to do this?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with all these helpers? Can you show the view?

Comment: by default all views render inside a < section > tag, so sometimes when I need something outside the scope I specify with those helpers. Anyways what I want it to DRY that code.

Answer (score 2):

```
def helper what
  content_for(what) { send "page_#{what}" }
end
```